# Python | Multiprocessing a Method using list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess a method using list elements.

Every time, I need to pass group of arguments along with new list item.
I tried below code, but not able to achieve working parallelism.

> fun(list_element,arg1,arg2)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun(each_item, arg1, arg2):
        
    print('start fun')

    print("fun in this function")
    
    print('end fun')

def main():

    compute_HostList = ['abc.xyz.com', 'def.xyz.com', 'mno.xyz.com']

    #Given list
    print("Given Compute list: ",compute_HostList)
    
    # Each element as list
    New_OS_Compute_List= [[x] for x in compute_HostList]

    # Print
    print("The new lists of lists: ",New_OS_Compute_List)

    for each_item in NewList:
        print("item_in_list:", each_item)
        p = Process(target=fun, args=(each_item, arg1, arg2))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    """
    #I also tried this using zip, but not working.
    for every in New_OS_Compute_List:
        tasks = [*zip(every, "OS DBAAS", "dbcs_patching")]
        with Pool(5) as pool:
            pool.starmap(decideTypeOfPatch, iterable=tasks)
    """
            
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('start main')
    main()
    print('end main')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `p.start()` immediately followed by `p.join()`, it does what you told it to do ;-) That is, it runs the process, and then just sits there waiting for the process to finish. So you get no useful parallelism.

So instead of

```
        p = Process(target=fun, args=(each_item, arg1, arg2))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

save the process objects in a list instead:

```
    plist = []
    ...
        p = Process(target=fun, args=(each_item, arg1, arg2))
        plist.append(p)
        p.start()
```

and *after* that loop is over wait for them to end:

```
    for p in plist:
        p.join()
```